# Change of pointer value at single run

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to build an Oct tree structure but the value of pointer seems changed during the run. insert() simulates insertion by randomly add children to the parent node and show() is used to display all elements along path.

Every time the insert() and show() print the node and their children, but the result is not consistence.

```
geometry.h
#pragma once
#include<random>
class Box
{
public:
    Box * parent;
    Box ** children;
public:
    Box()
    {
        parent = nullptr;
        children = new Box*[8];
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            children[i] = nullptr;
        }
    }
    Box(const Box &rhs)
    {
        parent = rhs.parent;
        children = new Box*[8];
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            children[i] = nullptr;
        }
    }
    Box & operator =(const Box &rhs)
    {
        if (this == &rhs)
        {
            return *this;
        }
        else
        {
            parent = nullptr;
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                children[i] = nullptr;
            }
        }
    }

};


class Tree
{
public:
    Box rootnode;
    int depth;
    Tree(int _depth) { depth = _depth; }
    void insert()
    {
        Box * temp;
        temp = &rootnode;
        for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++)
        {
            std::cout << temp << std::endl;
            //random choose a child
            int p=rand()%8;
            std::cout << p << std::endl;
            //creat a new child node and save the 
            //address to children
            temp->children[p] = new Box();
            for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++)
            {
                std::cout << temp->children[k] << " ";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
            // go to the next layer
            temp = temp->children[p];

            std::cout << temp <<"\n\n\n";

        }
    }

    void show()
    {
        Box * temp;
        temp = &rootnode;
        for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++)
        {

            std::cout << temp << std::endl;
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                std::cout << temp->children[j] << "  ";
                // if it have a child go to that child node
                if (!(temp->children[j] == nullptr))
                {
                    temp = temp->children[j];
                }
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;

        }
    }

};

#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include"geometry.h"

int main()
{
    Tree thistree(9);
    thistree.insert();
    thistree.show();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know this is not a good way to implement Oct tree, I just want to know why this not working, perheps becuase the "nullptr" initialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `show()` you're updating `temp` while still looping through its children:

```c
    ...
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {
        std::cout << temp->children[j] << "  ";
        // if it have a child go to that child node
        if (!(temp->children[j] == nullptr))
        {
>>>>        temp = temp->children[j];
        }
    }
```

You could use an auxiliary variable to store the pointer to the node to be used on the next level and then update `temp` outside of the loop, e.g.:

```c
    Box* next = nullptr;
    ...

    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {
        std::cout << temp->children[j] << "  ";
        // if it have a child go to that child node
        if (!(temp->children[j] == nullptr))
        {
            next = temp->children[j];
        }
    }
    temp = next;
```

Answer (score 1):

Does it change during a single run, or between the runs?

Since you are using dynamic memory, the adresses where your data is stored (the pointer value) can change from run to run.

Comment: Thanks for you attention, I think it changed during single run@florgeng